Get the Operating system details of the in-place upgraded Azure VM using Azure PowerShell
I am using below script to create report of the hosts with Operating system. I noticed some of the VMs have Source Image Offer different than Operating system as those were upgraded in-place.
Is there way to fetch this information from Azure PowerShell?
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName my-rg -Name myhostname1
$offer = $vm.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Offer  # Windows-10
$sku = $vm.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Sku      # win10-22h2-ent-g2

Expected outcome is: Windows (Windows 11 Enterprise).


Are you looking for solutions only in Azure PowerShell, or are you also open to using Azure CLI?

You can use this PowerShell script to fetch VM image information.
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "networktest-vnet" -Name "Venkat-vm"
$vmName = $vm.Name
$osType = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType
$imageReference = $vm.StorageProfile.ImageReference, Here is my output

Are you able to find the string you're looking for if you output your object as a json string, e.g. $vm | ConvertTo-Json | Out-String?

Hello @RuiJarimba, I tried this but the information is null : "ComputerName": null,   "OsName": null,  "OsVersion": null,.

@VenkatV, the accessor $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType only yields Windows but there are Other Versions viz., Windows-11. I am already using StorageProfile accessor but its not correct.

Can you please check my output and confirm if this is what you are looking for?

You can find the same operating system details in the source image plan; both values represent the same information but are in different formats: Windows (Windows 11 Enterprise N) and win11-22h2-entn

No, That is incorrect, as you see in the question details. Image Ref and OS are different.

How is that possible? For me, both are showing the same information.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Get the Operating system details of the in-place upgraded Azure VM using Azure PowerShell

In your case, the Source Image Offer is different from the Operating system. You can find the correct Operating System information using the command below.
$VMinfo= Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'networktest-vnet' -VMName 'Venkat-vm' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptString "Systeminfo"

This will fetch the VM OS information available in Systeminfo, not from the azure portal, allowing you to find the correct information.

Here is the Azure PowerShell command to fetch the VM Source Image Offer details which are available in azure portal.
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "networktest-vnet" -Name "Venkat-vm"
$vmName = $vm.Name
$osType = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType
$imageReference = $vm.StorageProfile.ImageReference


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I have shared the output image as proof, just as I did in my environment. The same command has already been provided in code format

Have you tried this? by adding -Status
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "my-vm-rg" -Name "myvm" -Status | Format-List *

Which also return the OS namd and version
result:
ResourceGroupName         : my-vm-rg
Name                      : myvm
ComputerName              : myvm
OsName                    : Windows Server 2022 Datacenter
OsVersion                 : 10.0.20348.2762
HyperVGeneration          : V2
AssignedHost              :
BootDiagnostics           : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.BootDiagnosticsInstanceView

